# Как удалить теги на странице?

Tags: javascript

через код kod.js подгружаются данные на html страницу. Мне нужно по кнопке без перезагрузки страницы удалять скопившиеся данные, которые находятся между тегами `<li></li>` как это сделать?

```
<div id="result_strip">  
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul class="collector"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: дак с периодичностью  или по кнопке?

Comment: @teran по кнопке, периодичность я сам выберу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно будет проще отдельно собрать все li, стереть всё содержимое thumbnails и пихнуть элементы li обратно, чем разбираться, что там между ними оказалось.

```js
let del = document.getElementById('js-delete');
let thumbnails = document.querySelector('.thumbnails');

del.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let li = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnails li');
  thumbnails.innerHTML = "";
  Array.from(li).forEach( e => thumbnails.appendChild(e) );
});
```

```html
<button id="js-delete">Удалить</button>
<div id="result_strip">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>111</li>
    скопившиеся данные...
    <li>222</li>
    которые между тегами...
    <li>333</li>
    <span>или тег...</span>
  </ul>
  <ul class="collector"></ul>
</div>
```

Чуть менее требовательный к знаниям код:

```js
var del = document.getElementById('js-delete');
var thumbnails = document.querySelector('.thumbnails');

del.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var li = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnails li');
  thumbnails.innerHTML = "";
  for( var i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ){
    thumbnails.appendChild( li[i] );
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="js-delete">Удалить</button>
<div id="result_strip">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>111</li>
    скопившиеся данные...
    <li>222</li>
    которые между тегами...
    <li>333</li>
    <span>или тег...</span>
  </ul>
  <ul class="collector"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, я тоже через батон сделал, само удаление кнопки только) костыль)

Comment: @Bloom ой, так я неправильно понял вопрос - код удаляет то, что между тегами li, а не внутри тегов)) Если надо было просто стереть содержимое thumbnails, достаточно было бы строчки `thumbnails.innerHTML = "";` )